# FileSystemWatcher Class in C++

Tags: c++, windows

Can anyone provide any examples of this class that capture events e.g. file creation and output them to a file please?

I have code in C#, that does this, but have little experience with C++

Answer (score 4):

[This](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/files/directorychangewatcher.aspx) is my preferred example code for the equivalent Win32 API [ReadDirectoryChangesW](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365465%28VS.85%29.aspx).  In a previous job, we used a derivative of this in production code with good results.

It's hard to code correctly to this API - I would re-use this, if you can.

Comment: Are there any command line options available for this program?

Comment: See the section in the article on `Console Applications`.  You would use the class mentioned `CDirectoryChangeWatcher` in writing your app, and then you can implement required command-line options in your application.